# How to identify all available wifi networks programmatically on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi

I want to identify all the available wifi networks currently available. I am checking the file at path

/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.wifi.plist

But it gives all the networks to which iPhone has connected till date. It does not give currently available networks.

How to do it? It's ok even if it's a private API. I have to do it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can access the available wifi's ssid in your iPhone app currently . I tried with some API but Apple rejected the App saying its a private API. I also sent my query to Apple Developer support and they replied saying this is not possible in current iOS version.

Comment: Hi..Bharath..i need that private API..because my app is product based.I have tried Stumbler.but i didn't get available networks.So can you please tell Which private API you uesd???